# Regex using result for replace String

Tags: java, regex

I want select all the text between `&lt;h3&gt;` and `/h3&gt; &lt;`. After selection I like to replace the value of my String with the result. In the following example the result should be *Basic Information*

```
String test="&lt;h3&gt;Basic Information&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;div&gt;";
test = test.replaceAll("&lt;h3&gt;(.*?)&lt;/h3&gt;", "$1");
```

But at the moment the result is

> *Basic Information &lt;div&gt;*

Comment: I don't see why you'd expect to get only *"Basic Information"* as a result with this code. Are you sure that `replaceAll` is really what you want? Perhaps you rather need to extract the match instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With regex you can do:

```
String test="&lt;h3&gt;Basic Information&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;div&gt;";
String repl = test.replaceFirst(".*&lt;h3&gt;([^&]+).*/h3&gt; &lt;.*", "$1");
//=> Basic Information
```

Though you can avoid regex altogether and use `String` APIs to extract same text as well.

Alternatively you can use this regex for matching:

```
&lt;h3&gt;([^&]+).*/h3&gt; &lt;
```

and grab captured group #1 using `Pattern` and `Matches` APIs.

Comment: yes, one example would be to use String splits just for performance sake. Unless the use if for something bigger. These are actually xml snippets so if they become big enough maybe a SAX parser could do the job better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&lt;h3&gt;(.*)&lt;\\/h3&gt;");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("&lt;h3&gt;Basic Information&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;div&gt;");
matcher.find();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
matcher.appendReplacement(sb,"$1");
String result = sb.toString();
```

The reason why you cannot do that with just replaceFirst it's because the `appendTail` method is called at the end of the `replaceFirst` method. The matcher will replace the groups you did not specified with **empty**,the groups you did specified with their **value** and of course the non-matching bits which well, since no match was created for them, they do not get replaced at all.

In the case of your query:

**group 0**: <h3>

**group 1**: Basic Information

**group 0**: </h3>

**non-match**: <div>

This is just a generic example of what you can do with the matchers. Of course if you just want the group in specific... Well just use:

```
matcher.group(1)
```

Comment: Why use the `StringBuffer` instead of just calling `group(1)`? And `sb.toString;` is not valid java.

Comment: This is just an example. Of course you can use group for it. I mean if you just want to replace groups without having the unmatched Strings about then StringBuffer is still better. If you just want one specific group... well just get the group. I just edited it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic btw, care to explain what do you mean by `sb.toString()` is not Java?  AFAIK, `StringBuffer`  contents are converted to string by the `toString()` method.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Another thing that you can do is to look at the API to see if sb.toString() is java or not:  `@Override public synchronized String toString() { if (toStringCache == null) { toStringCache = Arrays.copyOfRange(value, 0, count);} return new String(toStringCache, true);}`... when I look at the API it looks prety valid java hey :)

Comment: It's not valid Java without parentheses. You wrote `sb.toString` instead of `sb.toString()`, and you weren't returning the value anywhere (which is legal but meaningless).

Comment: @RealSkeptic As I said. It's just an example. It's not even a method, but thanks for the remark anyways. I've corrected it.